# Getting an App APK

Tags: android

Hey guys and girls for a the past week I've grown a lot of interest in android studio (even without knowing quite much about it) I decided to create an app that I deemed quite useful. However the app required maps to be integrated in it and I really did not know what I was doing and at one point I started messing with the settings and then all hell broke loose and I kept getting AAPT2 errors and I even tried to fix this issue with the gradle properties line that you add (I forgot the line of code to add). Anyways it still didnt work. However I rembered that I always kept the good version (before I broke everything) of the app on my phone. So when I go in my phone the app is there and it works just fine. Ive tried so many things to get the source code from the app on my phone without any succes. My question is, how can I get the source code back from the working app onto my laptop to continue coding in android studio? If it helps I am using Linux 18.04 LTS and running the newest version of android studio. Thank you for any help from you guys. This means a lot to me.

Comment: Reason above why u should use git.

Comment: How could I use git in this case then with Linux?

Comment: there is no use case of git in situation, its just good to store source code on git/github. Try git for future developments. For your situation u can use online java decompilers for extracting source code from apk but u cant just copy paste in androdi studio. Need to work on it then.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t get back the ‘source code’ from an already compiled app.

You should consider using some version control platforms like git from the next time